Performance issues extracting large tables from DB2 using ibm_db in Python
I'm using the ibm_db Python library to extract data from a large DB2 table (>50GB) and save it in chunks to a CSV file. I've experimented with different chunk sizes, but the extraction process remains slow. After running for about 30 minutes, I also notice a significant decrease in speed. I'm not sure whether the issue lies with how I'm paginating the query (using OFFSET), the chunk size, or the way I'm writing to the CSV file.
Here’s a simplified version of my code:
import csv
import ibm_db

chunk =0
offset = 500000

with open(csv_file_path, mode = "w", newline="") as csvfile:
    csv_writer = None
    
    while True:
        query=f"{sql} offset {offset} rows fetch next {chunk} rows only"
        Stmt = ibm_db.exec_immediate(conn, query)
        row = ibm_db.fetch_assoc(stmt)
        
        if not row:
            break
        while row:
        
            if first_chunk:
                header = row.keys()
                csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames = header)
                first_chunk = False
                
            csv_writer.writerow(row)
            row = ibm_db.fetch_assoc(stmt)
        offset += chunk
        
ibm_db.close(conn)

I've experimented with different chunk sizes, but there seems to diminishing returns in terms of memory usage vs extraction speed.

I don't think doing it in chunks will speed things up.

Does ibm_db need to buffer the entire result set in memory? Is there a way to disable that, so it will read rows incrementally?

The chunking was done for memory purposes, less so speed. I haven't found a way to buffer the result set for ibm_db yet either.

The problem is that on the DB server, implementing offset X rows fetch next Y rows only is an O(x) operation. It has to generate the first X rows so it can skip over them. It's like processing a file from the Nth line -- you have to read the first N lines first.

Wrong tool for the job? Using python for non-trivial exports to CSV is unwise. Apart from functional issues the main trouble is slow speed. Even after fixing the pagination to avoid re-running the query multiple times with OFFSET etc, which will help a little, it will still be slow. Consider using dedicated export tools, which you can either trigger from python (sproc admin_cmd for export, and stream/file-transfer to target-environment), or invoke directly locally using the fat Db2-client locally. Also allows easier parallelism.

To improve prefomance:
1. You can paginate using keyset pagination - it avoids rescanning all previous rows as offset does. For that you may use any indexed column (like id in my example).
query = f"SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id > {last_id} ORDER BY id ASC FETCH NEXT {chunk} ROWS ONLY"

2. Also you can write to CSV in batches to reduce I/O overhead.
Example:
import csv
import ibm_db

last_id = 0  # or any value, depending on your data
chunk_size = 50000
buffer_size = 10000  # adjust based on memory limits
rows_buffer = []

with open(csv_file_path, mode="w", newline="") as csvfile:
    csv_writer = None

    while True:
        query = f"SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id > {last_id} ORDER BY id ASC FETCH NEXT {chunk_size} ROWS ONLY"
        stmt = ibm_db.exec_immediate(conn, query)
        row = ibm_db.fetch_assoc(stmt)

        if not row:
            break
            
        while row:
            if not csv_writer:
                header = row.keys()
                csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=header)
                csv_writer.writeheader()

            rows_buffer.append(row)
            
            if len(rows_buffer) >= buffer_size:
                csv_writer.writerows(rows_buffer)
                rows_buffer = []  # clear buffer

            last_id = row['id']  # update last_id for pagination
            row = ibm_db.fetch_assoc(stmt)

    # write remaining rows
    if rows_buffer:
        csv_writer.writerows(rows_buffer)

ibm_db.close(conn)

